# Opacity for only a part of background image - CSS

Tags: css, background, header, background-image, opacity

Do you maybe know how (and if) I can add an opacity for the background image but only to PART of it?

The effect should be like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYvaU.png.

I have only added the image as a background but I cannot find any solution for this oppacity.
My HTML:

```
<header>
      <img src="images/logo.svg" />
      <h1>A history of everything you copy</h1>
      <p>
        Clipboard allows you to track and organize everything you copy.
        Instantly access your clipboard on all your devices.
      </p>
    </header>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/bg-header-desktop.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 50px 150px;
  }
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(210, 10%, 33%);
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

header > p {
  color: hsl(201, 11%, 66%);
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

I have tried to use mask-image but it didn't work:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/bg-header-desktop.png);
    mask-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), transparent 74%);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 50px 150px;
  }
}
```

Do you have maybe any idea if I can give an opacity only for the bottom part of this background image using CSS?

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

With more than 1 background, you can put image in 1 and opacity on the other.

You can change 2nd background color as you want. It's opacity value is given by the RGBA background color (here 0.75 in the snippet).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 10em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/22/1280/600");
}

.wrapper1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: inset(50% 0 0 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper1"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

Look at the snipper in full scree, for this demo I put width 100vw, so in small result is "strange"